# Cant get Image url from intent

Tags: android, appcelerator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display jpg image from intent in imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590881/display-jpg-image-from-intent-in-imageview)

Im trying to get the image file path from the gallery when I click "share with" > my app.
How do I catch the path of the image I selected?

I added this in the Manifest right between the  section.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/postscript" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-tar" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/msword" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.visio" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-debian-package" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/csv" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/rtf" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The manifest seems correct (`image/*` should be enough anyway), you are probably doing something wrong in your code. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590881/display-jpg-image-from-intent-in-imageview)