# Display jpg image from intent in imageview

Tags: android, android-intent

How to display an Image received from an `"android.intent.action.SEND"` in an `imageview`?
The user selects my app from the list of apps to share an image. The image is `sent via intent` and my activity opens up but how to use this image in an imageview?

using

```
Bitmap  thumbnail = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().get("data");
```

does not help and

```
getIntent().getType() returns image/jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receving Image in Intent, So you have to update your Manifest as:

```
<activity android:name=".Your_Activity" >
    ...
    ...
    <intent-filter>
    ...
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity
```

Then Activity needs:

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
// Get intent, action and MIME type
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            YourImageView.setImageUri(imageUri);
        }
    }
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! it worked like a charm! Just a little update, the function name is setImageURI.

Comment: Oh, yes that(setImageUri) was my mistake, you also informed me to use setImageURI()... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 BitMap thumnail= (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("data");
 yourImageViewId.setImageBitmap(receiptimage);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap` implements `Parcelable` interface. So to pass it use

```
intent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmap);
```

and to retrieve it use:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
```

and use [ImageView.setImageBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29).

EDIT: see [Receiving Content from Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

Comment: The putExtra thing is not in my control. it is the external apps that control the firing of intent and the gallery is sending jpg images and not bitmaps. therefore this solution wont work in my case. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: use Chintan's answer or read http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html it is suited for your scenario